# postgresql: foreign key to either tableA or tableB

Tags: sql, database, database-design, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to define the schema of a database on with Postgresql 8.

I have 2 tables:

`Journals`, `Books`

that define the publications I have

```
Journal:
id_j, name, issn, other fields

Book:
id_b, name, isbn, author, other fields
```

and I have another table `Scans` that logically refers both the previous tables.

```
Scans:
id, medium, source, status
```

each `Journal` or `Book` can have more than one `Scan`, but each `Scan` can refer only one `Journal` or `Book`.

To formalize this, my first idea was to put two foreign keys in `Scans` like

```
Scans:
id, medium, source, status, id_j, id_b
```

and fill in either `id_j` or `id_b`

but this solution seems to me a bit weird.

I don't want (if it is possible) to define the table in a way like this:

```
Scans:
id, medium, source, status, id_other_table, other_table_name
```

because I would like to have a formal connection between the tables.

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE source (
       type CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (type IN ('J', 'B')),
       id INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (type, id)
);

CREATE TABLE book (
       type CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(type = 'B'), id INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id),
       FOREIGN KEY (type, id) REFERENCES source (type, id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE journal (
       type CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(type = 'J'), id INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id),
       FOREIGN KEY (type, id) REFERENCES source (type, id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE scan (id INT NOT NULL, sourcetype CHAR(1) NOT NULL, sourceid INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id),
       FOREIGN KEY (sourcetype, sourceid) REFERENCES source (type, id)
);
```

With this design, you should not delete records directly from `book` or `journal`: instead, delete from table `source` which will cascade the operation to the appropriate table.

You can move the attributes that are common to `book` and `journal` to `source`.

Comment: Yea, normalization usually helps. Denormalize database after normalization, not before.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how can you delete from source if a record is referenced from books?

Comment: @Julian: if you declare your foreign keys as described in the post, it will delete the referencing records as well.

Comment: You are perfectly right even if I don't quite understand how the DELETE propagate the other way around from referenced record to the one pointing to it. But I just tested and it works. Maybe it just simulates two tables sharing a single primary key columns combinations.

Can you pls post this as an answer to my question below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77560312/how-to-optimaly-delete-records-from-a-parent-and-associated-children-table

Comment: @Julian: what exactly do you want me to post? This looks to be the answer to your question as well, if you ignore its flawed premise of this not working in PostgreSQL. Do you want me to close it as a duplicate, so that people would get redirected here?

Comment: Yes u can either make a duplicate or post an answer with a link to this. Our structure was not exactly like the one in this answer but can be change to be like that. I guess an answer pointing to this post would be a better option. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to consider is to explicitly have 2 nullable foreign keys columns in the table, along with a constraint that one of them (and only one) should not be null:

```sql
CREATE TABLE scan (id INT NOT NULL, journal_id int, book_id int,
       PRIMARY KEY (id),
       FOREIGN KEY (journal_id) REFERENCES journal (id),
       FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book (id),
       CONSTRAINT check_single_source CHECK (num_nonnulls(book_id,journal_id) = 1)
);
```