# How to optimaly delete records from a parent and associated children table

Tags: sql, postgresql, cascading-deletes

We have a three table structure similar with the below:

```sql
CREATE table publications (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY ,
    type CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (type IN ('B', 'P')),
    title VARCHAR(60),
    publish_date DATE,
    author VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE table books (
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY ,
   isbn VARCHAR(20),
   pages_no INT,
  CONSTRAINT books_fk FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES publications(id)
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY ,
   comments_no INT,
   likes_no INT,
   unlikes_no INT,
   CONSTRAINT posts_fk FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES publications(id)
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO publications (id, type, title, publish_date, author)
VALUES('5a428ea2-b5a9-48e0-8865-e2fe5f653473', 'B', 'Some book title', current_date, 'John Doe');

INSERT INTO publications (id, type, title, publish_date, author)
VALUES('15a7a75a-3ac7-4628-8735-174d8709bc4a', 'P', 'Some post title', current_date, 'John Doe');

INSERT INTO books (id, isbn, pages_no)
VALUES ('5a428ea2-b5a9-48e0-8865-e2fe5f653473', 'some isbn', 123);

INSERT INTO posts (id, comments_no, likes_no, unlikes_no)
VALUES ('15a7a75a-3ac7-4628-8735-174d8709bc4a', 10, 20, 3);
```

The reason behind this structure is that our architects put together an API that returns all publications for an author irrespective they are books or posts. Also they want to delete a publication based on its id.

Solution 2 of the accepted answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623437/delete-from-table1-and-records-associated-in-table-2) shows a way to delete from both parent table and associated child table with only one single SQL, but that, if works, is a MySQL solution and it does not work in PostgreSQL.

So my question is:
**Is there a way to only have one DELETE statement and delete one publication from both parent table and its associated table based on its id without knowing the type of the publication?**

If this cannot be done in an elegant way, what would be a better way to achieve this? One way that came to my mind was to have a `book_id` and a `post_id` in publications table (only one of them `NOT NULL`) and have two `FOREGN KEY` constraints to `books` and and respective `posts` tables with `CASCADE DELETE` but this looks a bit dirty solution to myself because it can become a bit nasty when the number of child tables increases.

Another thing that came to my mind was to have `books` and `posts` tables inherit from `publications` and keep the `publication` empty and only populate the data in `books` and respective `posts` but this again looked a bit complex and our use case does not seem like the reason inheritance concept was added.

Comment: Looks like I linked the wrong ticket when closing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509950/postgresql-foreign-key-to-either-tablea-or-tableb/2510008?noredirect=1#comment136734916_2510008 here's the right one. Any way to fix it? @mod

Comment: @Quassnoi won't it be easier to re-open, then close with the right link? @Julian here's a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nr64TI0y). I think you were on the right track, it's just that the `on delete casade` works fine on the child already (like you have it set up now), and you don't need to link back from the parent. If you wanted the reverse, a `delete from books` to cascade to `publications`, then you'd need that `book_id` link in there.

Comment: @Zegarek: I can't vote close twice

Comment: @Quassnoi Now it's me that initiated the process, using the link from your comment above. Does it let you cast a vote now?

Comment: @Zegarek: no, it doesn't

Comment: Thank you guys. It pointed to the other answer but the question is still a duplicate so someone facing the same issue going there could read the right way of addressing this once it clicks on your link.